# How to scale down my image and display it in fullscreen on Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I created an empty Single View based iOS app in Xcode;
placed an `imageView` into my storyboard;

and then update `viewDidLoad` for my `viewController` as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Image" ofType: @"jpg"];
    NSURL *fileNameAndPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL: fileNameAndPath];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage: beginImage];
    self.imageView.image = newImage;
}
```

No matter what mode I choose for the `imageView` at the storyboard: (AspectFit/AspectFill/Redrew/...), it doesn't show nicely in the screen.
How do I make it scale down to the screen size and show in full screen?
Same problem for iPhone and iPad simulators.

Comment: What means "it doesn't show nicely in the screen"?

Comment: Please check your sample:`beginImage` is initialised but never used. `newImage` is used but seems to be not initialised.

Comment: @Thedude : Just recreated a new project and now it shows OK; i mean, it no part of the image has been clipped away. not sure what happened. Does it have to do with the "wCompact hRegular" settings below the ViewController in the storyboard ?